# call function of outter class from inner anonymous class (same class as outter)

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class

How to call the callback function of outter class without using a helper variable like i did in my example below.

Please note that the solution described in [Calling outer class function from inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808501/calling-outer-class-function-from-inner-class) probably won't work.

```
public abstract class Job {
    public void callback();
}

public abstract class ExtendedJob extends Job {

    protected void handleResult() {
        // workaround for accessing the outter class
        final ExtendedJob outter = this;

        new ExtendedJob {
            public void callback() {
                // can i do the same without the outter variable?
                outter.callback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think you can do without the variable, but its not like using the helper variable will be harmful.

Comment: @DirkyJerky it works, look at first answer :)

Comment: How is this different from this except you have an extra extends means it has visibility to all members ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043170/java-calling-outer-class-method-in-anonymous-inner-class

Comment: I was thinking that, as the inner class is an ExtendedJob as well, `ExtendedJob.this` would be equivalent to just `this`. But i guess the inner class actually is only a subclass of ExtendedJob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do the trick

```
ExtendedJob.this.callback();
```

Comment: No, that syntax is backwards: it's `ExtendedJob.this.callback()`.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, I was just starting eclipse to check which version is correct ;)

Comment: I should've tried it myself instead of just thinking that there's no way it would work. I though it won't work because the inner class is also an ExtendedJob class. I guess it's actually a child class of ExtendedJob, anonymous, but child nevertheless.

Comment: @tkSimon I guess you've confused `ExtendedJob.this.foo()` with `super.foo()` or something similar. That's actually strange that you can only call direct superclass' methods, but not methods of arbitrary class in the inheritance chain.