# Android - Call non-static function from dialog

Tags: java, android

I am making an gaming app that brings up an `AlertDialog` when the game is over. Inside the dialog, there is a `positiveButton` to play again.

What I would like the button to call the functions I have already made for the `onCreate()` method, but I do not want the functions to be static.

Here is what my `onCreate` method looks like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setup();
}
```

I would like to call the `setup()` function from the dialog.

How would one go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some pieces of code will be easier to understand your question.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling onCreate because the Activity is already created. Please edit your question to include what you are trying to do

Comment: @cricket_007 I am not calling `onCreate`, I'm just calling the same functions I call within the `onCreate` method.

Comment: You should either be able to do `MyActivity.this.foo()` or `foo()` directly. I don't understand why you wouldn't be able to unless your Dialog is not in the Activity class

Comment: @autobot_101 I have edited the question to include some code.

Comment: Please also show where the Dialog is created

Comment: @The_Grits What have you tried to call in `positiveButton` callback?

Comment: Why don't you post the code of the dialog so we can  see what you are doing.  Note that this in an anonymous object refers to the object encapsulating the call.

Comment: I can't access the code as of right now, but I can tell you all that I have an `onClickListener` on `this` (referring to the `positiveButton`) that I was trying to call `setup()` in the `onClick` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the basic idea off of @arsent's answer, this is what worked for me:

```
Main mainActivity = (Main)getActivity();
mainActivity.setup();
```

Thanks everybody for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be static. If your callback for positive button is an anonymous or a non-static inner class than it can access non static methods of the outer class. You can just call `setup()` from the callback.

Of course, this won't be the case if you are not using anonymous or non-static inner callback class in which case you have to make the Activity method static to be able to call it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9043349/1162784) shows how to do it.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. I'll vote your answer up and test it tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: Your answer didn't solve my problem, but it did get me a lot closer. If you want to see what worked, I'm posting a solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great. If you are doing it in a fragment that's the way to go! I'm glad I was useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an `DialogFragment` as I do in my latest project you can create an interface. For example:

```
/// Inside my DialogFragment
public interface ChooserListener {
    public void setupDialogListener();
}

// Inside my DialogFragment
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mListener = (ChooserListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()+" must implement the ChooserListener interface.");
    }
}
```

And then you can just implement the interface into your application with `... implements YourDialogFragment.YourListener`. Now you must implement the predefined functions in your listener into your main activity and you can simply trigger them from inside of the Dialog. For further reference see [Dialogs - Passing Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents)

In your case you should write a function like this:

```
public void setupDialogListener() {
     setup();
}
```

Comment: thx cricket_007. didn't found the time to simplify my expression. Sorry :D