# Kotlin: calling outer class method in object expression

Tags: kotlin

My question is almost like this question [Java: calling outer class method in anonymous inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043170/java-calling-outer-class-method-in-anonymous-inner-class) .
But this time we are in Kotlin.

As the example below, I want to call `funB()` in the object expression, but I only made two failures.

```
class A {
    lateinit var funA: () -> Unit
    lateinit var funB: () -> Unit

    fun funC()  {
        var b = object : B() {
            override fun funB() {
                funA() // A.funA()

                // Two attempts to fail
                funB() // b.funB(), not my expect
                A::funB() // compile error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: `this@A.funB()`

Comment: @yole that's an answer ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can qualify `this` with a @ to obtain an equivalent of java: `MyClass.this` 
 ->`this@MyClass`

Then in your case, you can call:

```
this@A.funB()
```

---

From the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified):

> To access this from an outer scope (a class, or extension function, or labeled function literal with receiver) we write this@label where @label is a label on the scope this is meant to be from:

```
class A { // implicit label @A
    inner class B { // implicit label @B
        fun Int.foo() { // implicit label @foo
            val a = this@A // A's this
            val b = this@B // B's this

            val c = this // foo()'s receiver, an Int
            val c1 = this@foo // foo()'s receiver, an Int

            val funLit = lambda@ fun String.() {
                val d = this // funLit's receiver
            }


            val funLit2 = { s: String ->
                // foo()'s receiver, since enclosing lambda expression
                // doesn't have any receiver
                val d1 = this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! So detailed!