# Listview initialization issue

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to initialize a `ListView` and then I get errors saying that the method `setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>)` is undefined for the type `SurveyActivity`. I also get that `getListView()` is undefined. Any ideas? Code:

```
public class SurveyActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
CheckBox cb;
String myChoice1;
String myChoice2;
String myChoice3;
String myChoice4;
String myChoice5;
String myChoice6;
String myChoice7;
String myChoice8;
String myChoice9;
String myChoice10;



RadioButton radio1,radio2,radio3,radio4,radio5,radio6,radio7,radio8,radio9,radio10;

RadioGroup rg1,rg2,rg3,rg4,rg5;
EditText text1,text2,text3;
//Button button1;
Button button2;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] countrie = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cars);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, countrie));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      });


    cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    //RadioGroup rg1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg1);
    RadioGroup rg2=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg2);
    RadioGroup rg3=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg3);
    RadioGroup rg4=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg4);
    RadioGroup rg5=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg5);
    //radio1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
   // radio2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    //radio3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    //radio4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio4);
    //radio5=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio5);
    radio6=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio6);
    radio7=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio7);
    radio8=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio8);
    radio9=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio9);
    radio10=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio10);

   // rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
 /*   rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            switch(checkedId)
            {
            case R.id.radio1:
                myChoice2 = "mazda";
                //text1.setText(myChoice);
                break;
            case R.id.radio2:
                myChoice2 = "Totota";
                //text1.setText(myChoice);
                break;
            case R.id.radio3:
                myChoice2 = "Nissan";
                //text1.setText(myChoice);
                break;
            case R.id.radio4:
                myChoice2 = "Hyundai";
                //text1.setText(myChoice);
                break;

            }

        }
    }); 
   */ 
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
    String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cars);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, countries);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    myChoice2=textView.getText().toString();
   //myChoice2="WORKING";


    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.Year_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

    Spinner spinner22 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.Wheel_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner22.setAdapter(adapter2);

    spinner22.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener1());




 rg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            switch(checkedId)
            {
            case R.id.radio5:
                myChoice5 = "1.8";
                //text1.setText(myChoice);
                break;
            case R.id.radio6:
                myChoice5 = "2.0";
                //text1.setText(myChoice);
                break;
            case R.id.radio7:
                myChoice5 = "2.3";
                //text1.setText(myChoice);
                break;

            }

        }
    });

 rg3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        switch(checkedId)
        {
        case R.id.radio8:
            myChoice6 = "Automatic";
            //text1.setText(myChoice);
            break;
        case R.id.radio9:
            myChoice6 = "Manual";
            //text1.setText(myChoice);
            break;


        }

        }
    });

 rg4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        switch(checkedId)
        {
        case R.id.radio10:
            myChoice9 = "Yes";
            //text1.setText(myChoice);
            break;
        case R.id.radio11:
            myChoice9 = "No";
            //text1.setText(myChoice);
            break;


        }

        }
    });

 rg5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        switch(checkedId)
        {
        case R.id.radio12:
            myChoice10 = "Yes";
            //text1.setText(myChoice);
            break;
        case R.id.radio13:
            myChoice10 = "No";
            //text1.setText(myChoice);
            break;


        }

        }
    });












    //text1.setText(myChoice1);
//    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);
//  button1.setOnClickListener(new clicker());
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button02);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new clicker());

    /* Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
*/
}

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
      //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The planet is " +
        //  parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        myChoice3=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}


public class MyOnItemSelectedListener1 implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
      //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The planet is " +
        //  parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        myChoice8=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}


    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
    boolean isChecked) 
    {
        if (isChecked) 
            {
            cb.setText("Yes , I have a car!");
            myChoice1="I have a car ";

            }
        else 
            {
            cb.setText("  ");
            }

                    if (isChecked) {
                    TextView tv= new TextView (this);
                    tv.setText("You have a car , nice!");
                      }
    }


        class clicker implements Button.OnClickListener
        {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {                        
                  /*  if(v==button1)
                    {
                        //text1.setText(myChoice1);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 

                            "~~~~Successfully submitted AFTER u hit the button below~~~", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } */

                       if(v==button2)
                    {

                           text2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etext2);
                           text1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etext1);
                           //text2.setText(text1.getText().toString());
                           myChoice4=text1.getText().toString();
                           myChoice7=text2.getText().toString();
                        Intent viewDataIntent = new Intent(SurveyActivity.this, Survey2.class);
                        String myData = "You should see this";
                        viewDataIntent.putExtra("valueOne", myData);
                        viewDataIntent.putExtra("k1", myChoice1);
                        viewDataIntent.putExtra("k2", myChoice2);
                        viewDataIntent.putExtra("k3", myChoice3);
                        viewDataIntent.putExtra("k4", myChoice4);
                        viewDataIntent.putExtra("k5", myChoice5);
                        viewDataIntent.putExtra("k6", myChoice6);
                        viewDataIntent.putExtra("k7", myChoice7);
                        viewDataIntent.putExtra("k8", myChoice8);
                        viewDataIntent.putExtra("k9", myChoice9);
                        viewDataIntent.putExtra("k10", myChoice10);
                        startActivity(viewDataIntent);



                          // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),text1.getText(), 
                            //   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
        }



}
```

Here is my `Logcat`:

```
03-01 12:43:07.164: W/dalvikvm(802): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3938)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:362)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:305)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:474)
03-01 12:43:07.194: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: I found other question with the same error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039017/android-app-application-cannot-be-instantiated-due-to-nullpointerexception , from what I read it's tied to your OnClickListener inner classes.

Comment: will see , thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 2):

Extend `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`. If you extend `ListActivity` and set the content view like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

make sure that in the `main.xml` you have a `ListView` element with the id `@android:id/list`.

Comment: How do you initialize listview in xml?

Comment: <ListView
           
   android:id="@+id/list"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  ></ListView>

Comment: @da_scav_from_windy_city In `main.xml` add a `ListView` like this: <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

Comment: I put that in in the main xml , but still i am getting the same error

Comment: @da_scav_from_windy_city Edit your question and add the stacktrace from the `Logcat` with the exceptions and point in which line they appear.