# java.lang.RuntimeException mostly by Android 4.4 devies

Tags: android, crash

**Occasionally (rarely)**, the following crash is reported:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:507)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4334)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:138)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1259)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5034)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:795)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:611)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader (LoadedApk.java:368)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader (LoadedApk.java:321)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:500)
```

About 90% of them are from Android 4.4 devices.  Could anyone offer a tip on how to prevent this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039017/android-app-application-cannot-be-instantiated-due-to-nullpointerexception Check this seems like same error

Comment: I do not see much similarity.  Thank you for trying to help.